# Image under a Möbius transform

Tags: complex-analysis, maple, mathematica

Let $$\varphi:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{D},~z\mapsto\frac{z-i}{z+i}$$ be the biholomorphic map from the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}$ to the open unit disk $\mathbb{D}$.

I wonder how the image of this set under $\varphi$ looks like.

Is this possible with Mathematica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some images. Made with Maple (my code is not very pretty though).

[image: Set before transformation]

[image: Set after transformation]

**All the data here are approximate.**
The green circle is centered on $1+2i$ and of radius $2$.
The yellow circle is then centered on $1-2i$ and of radius $2$.
The most high red circle is centered on $-0.71+0.71i$ and of radius $0.14$. The most low then on $-0.71-0.71i$ with the same radius.
Finally the two others are centered on $-1+0.333i$ and $-1-0.333i$ with the same radius $0.333$.

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the english errors. :p

Comment: Knowing three points of each circle, you can compute the image of those three points and then solve a 3 equations / 3 unknowns system using the command "solve".